# Using both CAN1 & CAN2 both in STM32F446 properly?

Tags: driver, stm32, interrupt, can-bus, stm32f4

I want to use both CAN1 and CAN2 for my application with 500kbps and 125kbps speeds respectively. I have initialized both of them as per my requirements using HAL. Where in Tx is implemented in polling and Rx in interrupts. **CAN1 Tx and Rx working perfect. Coming to CAN2 Tx is working and Rx is not working.** Interrupt itself is not firing up for CAN2 Rx (HAL_CAN_RxFifo0MsgPendingCallback is not being called). I've read in datasheet that SRAM sharing process is happening between 2 CANs. I'm unable to comprehend that. Is that an issue?

I'm attaching the code also. Please check and help!
Little overview - all MCU clocks running at - 16 MHz using internal HSI, No filter in CAN configs

```html
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ MAIN FILE @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
CAN_HandleTypeDef hcan1;
CAN_HandleTypeDef hcan2;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
CAN_TxHeaderTypeDef txheader;
uint8_t txdata[8];
CAN_RxHeaderTypeDef RxHeader;
uint8_t RxData[8];
CAN_TxHeaderTypeDef txheader1;
uint8_t txdata1[8];
CAN_RxHeaderTypeDef RxHeader1;
uint8_t RxData1[8];
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_CAN1_Init(void);
static void MX_CAN2_Init(void);

int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
uint8_t fill = 0;
  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_CAN1_Init();
  MX_CAN2_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

      
    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
      
      txheader.DLC = 8;
      txheader.ExtId = 0x11111111;
      txheader.IDE = CAN_ID_EXT;
      txheader.RTR = CAN_RTR_DATA;
      for(uint8_t i = 0; i<8;i++)
      {
          txdata[i] = i;
      }
//      txdata[0] = fill;
      HAL_Delay(250);
      HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage(&hcan1,&txheader,txdata, (uint32_t *)CAN_TX_MAILBOX0);
      HAL_Delay(250);
      HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage(&hcan2,&txheader,txdata, (uint32_t *)CAN_TX_MAILBOX0);
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}


void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE3);
  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief CAN1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_CAN1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN1_Init 0 */
CAN_FilterTypeDef  sFilterConfig;
  /* USER CODE END CAN1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END CAN1_Init 1 */
  hcan1.Instance = CAN1;
  hcan1.Init.Prescaler = 2;
  hcan1.Init.Mode = CAN_MODE_NORMAL;
  hcan1.Init.SyncJumpWidth = CAN_SJW_1TQ;
  hcan1.Init.TimeSeg1 = CAN_BS1_13TQ;
  hcan1.Init.TimeSeg2 = CAN_BS2_2TQ;
  hcan1.Init.TimeTriggeredMode = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.AutoBusOff = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.AutoWakeUp = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.AutoRetransmission = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.ReceiveFifoLocked = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.TransmitFifoPriority = DISABLE;
  if (HAL_CAN_Init(&hcan1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN1_Init 2 */
  sFilterConfig.FilterBank = 0;
  sFilterConfig.FilterMode = CAN_FILTERMODE_IDMASK;
  sFilterConfig.FilterScale = CAN_FILTERSCALE_32BIT;
  sFilterConfig.FilterIdHigh = 0x0000;
  sFilterConfig.FilterIdLow = 0x0000;
  sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdHigh = 0x0000;
  sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdLow = 0x0000;
  sFilterConfig.FilterFIFOAssignment = CAN_RX_FIFO0;
  sFilterConfig.FilterActivation = ENABLE;
  sFilterConfig.SlaveStartFilterBank = 14;

  if (HAL_CAN_ConfigFilter(&hcan1, &sFilterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Filter configuration Error */
    Error_Handler();
  }
  
HAL_CAN_Start(&hcan1);
  
  /*##-4- Activate CAN RX notification #######################################*/
  if (HAL_CAN_ActivateNotification(&hcan1, CAN_IT_RX_FIFO0_MSG_PENDING) != HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Notification Error */
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE END CAN1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief CAN1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_CAN2_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN1_Init 0 */
CAN_FilterTypeDef  sFilterConfig;
  /* USER CODE END CAN1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END CAN1_Init 1 */
  hcan2.Instance = CAN2;
  hcan2.Init.Prescaler = 8;
  hcan2.Init.Mode = CAN_MODE_NORMAL;
  hcan2.Init.SyncJumpWidth = CAN_SJW_1TQ;
  hcan2.Init.TimeSeg1 = CAN_BS1_13TQ;
  hcan2.Init.TimeSeg2 = CAN_BS2_2TQ;
  hcan2.Init.TimeTriggeredMode = DISABLE;
  hcan2.Init.AutoBusOff = DISABLE;
  hcan2.Init.AutoWakeUp = DISABLE;
  hcan2.Init.AutoRetransmission = DISABLE;
  hcan2.Init.ReceiveFifoLocked = DISABLE;
  hcan2.Init.TransmitFifoPriority = DISABLE;
  if (HAL_CAN_Init(&hcan2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN1_Init 2 */
  sFilterConfig.FilterBank = 0;
  sFilterConfig.FilterMode = CAN_FILTERMODE_IDMASK;
  sFilterConfig.FilterScale = CAN_FILTERSCALE_32BIT;
  sFilterConfig.FilterIdHigh = 0x0000;
  sFilterConfig.FilterIdLow = 0x0000;
  sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdHigh = 0x0000;
  sFilterConfig.FilterMaskIdLow = 0x0000;
  sFilterConfig.FilterFIFOAssignment = CAN_RX_FIFO0;
  sFilterConfig.FilterActivation = ENABLE;
  sFilterConfig.SlaveStartFilterBank = 14;

  if (HAL_CAN_ConfigFilter(&hcan2, &sFilterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Filter configuration Error */
    Error_Handler();
  }
  

HAL_CAN_Start(&hcan2);
  
  /*##-4- Activate CAN RX notification #######################################*/
  if (HAL_CAN_ActivateNotification(&hcan2, CAN_IT_RX_FIFO0_MSG_PENDING) != HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Notification Error */
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE END CAN1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */
/**
  * @brief  Rx Fifo 0 message pending callback
  * @param  hcan: pointer to a CAN_HandleTypeDef structure that contains
  *         the configuration information for the specified CAN.
  * @retval None
  */
uint8_t cflag;
void HAL_CAN_RxFifo0MsgPendingCallback(CAN_HandleTypeDef *hcan)
{
  /* Get RX message */
  if (HAL_CAN_GetRxMessage(hcan, CAN_RX_FIFO0, &RxHeader, RxData) != HAL_OK)
  {
    /* Reception Error */
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /* Display LEDx */
  if ((RxHeader.StdId == 0x321) && (RxHeader.IDE == CAN_ID_STD) && (RxHeader.DLC == 2))
  {
    
  }
  /* Display LEDx */
  if ((RxHeader.ExtId == 0x11111111) && (RxHeader.IDE == CAN_ID_EXT) && (RxHeader.DLC == 8))
  {
      cflag = 1;
  }
  else
      cflag = 0;
}
/* USER CODE END 4 */

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ MSP FILE @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@


/**
  * Initializes the Global MSP.
  */
void HAL_MspInit(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END MspInit 0 */

  __HAL_RCC_SYSCFG_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* System interrupt init*/

  /* USER CODE BEGIN MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END MspInit 1 */
}

static uint32_t HAL_RCC_CAN1_CLK_ENABLED=0;

/**
* @brief CAN MSP Initialization
* This function configures the hardware resources used in this example
* @param hcan: CAN handle pointer
* @retval None
*/
void HAL_CAN_MspInit(CAN_HandleTypeDef* hcan)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
  if(hcan->Instance==CAN1)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN1_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END CAN1_MspInit 0 */
    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    HAL_RCC_CAN1_CLK_ENABLED++;
    if(HAL_RCC_CAN1_CLK_ENABLED==1){
      __HAL_RCC_CAN1_CLK_ENABLE();
    }

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
    /**CAN1 GPIO Configuration
    PA11     ------> CAN1_RX
    PA12     ------> CAN1_TX
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_11|GPIO_PIN_12;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF9_CAN1;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN1_MspInit 1 */
HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(CAN1_RX0_IRQn, 1, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(CAN1_RX0_IRQn);
  /* USER CODE END CAN1_MspInit 1 */
  }
  else if(hcan->Instance==CAN2)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN2_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END CAN2_MspInit 0 */
    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_CAN2_CLK_ENABLE();
    HAL_RCC_CAN1_CLK_ENABLED++;
    if(HAL_RCC_CAN1_CLK_ENABLED==1){
      __HAL_RCC_CAN1_CLK_ENABLE();
    }

    __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
    /**CAN2 GPIO Configuration
    PB12     ------> CAN2_RX
    PB13     ------> CAN2_TX
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_13;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_VERY_HIGH;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF9_CAN2;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* CAN2 interrupt Init */
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(CAN2_RX0_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(CAN2_RX0_IRQn);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN2_MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END CAN2_MspInit 1 */
  }

}

/**
* @brief CAN MSP De-Initialization
* This function freeze the hardware resources used in this example
* @param hcan: CAN handle pointer
* @retval None
*/
void HAL_CAN_MspDeInit(CAN_HandleTypeDef* hcan)
{
  if(hcan->Instance==CAN1)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN1_MspDeInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END CAN1_MspDeInit 0 */
    /* Peripheral clock disable */
    HAL_RCC_CAN1_CLK_ENABLED--;
    if(HAL_RCC_CAN1_CLK_ENABLED==0){
      __HAL_RCC_CAN1_CLK_DISABLE();
    }

    /**CAN1 GPIO Configuration
    PA11     ------> CAN1_RX
    PA12     ------> CAN1_TX
    */
    HAL_GPIO_DeInit(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_11|GPIO_PIN_12);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN1_MspDeInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END CAN1_MspDeInit 1 */
  }
  else if(hcan->Instance==CAN2)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN2_MspDeInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END CAN2_MspDeInit 0 */
    /* Peripheral clock disable */
    __HAL_RCC_CAN2_CLK_DISABLE();
    HAL_RCC_CAN1_CLK_ENABLED--;
    if(HAL_RCC_CAN1_CLK_ENABLED==0){
      __HAL_RCC_CAN1_CLK_DISABLE();
    }

    /**CAN2 GPIO Configuration
    PB12     ------> CAN2_RX
    PB13     ------> CAN2_TX
    */
    HAL_GPIO_DeInit(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_13);

    /* CAN2 interrupt DeInit */
    HAL_NVIC_DisableIRQ(CAN2_RX0_IRQn);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN2_MspDeInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END CAN2_MspDeInit 1 */
  }

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

/* USER CODE END 1 */

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ IT FILE @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_it.h"
/* External variables --------------------------------------------------------*/
extern CAN_HandleTypeDef hcan2;
/**
  * @brief This function handles System tick timer.
  */
void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysTick_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SysTick_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_IncTick();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysTick_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SysTick_IRQn 1 */
}

/******************************************************************************/
/* STM32F4xx Peripheral Interrupt Handlers                                    */
/* Add here the Interrupt Handlers for the used peripherals.                  */
/* For the available peripheral interrupt handler names,                      */
/* please refer to the startup file (startup_stm32f4xx.s).                    */
/******************************************************************************/

/**
  * @brief This function handles CAN2 RX0 interrupt.
  */
void CAN2_RX0_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN2_RX0_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END CAN2_RX0_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_CAN_IRQHandler(&hcan2);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN2_RX0_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END CAN2_RX0_IRQn 1 */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
/**
* @brief  This function handles CAN1 RX0 interrupt request.
* @param  None
* @retval None
*/
extern CAN_HandleTypeDef hcan1;
void CAN1_RX0_IRQHandler(void)
{
  HAL_CAN_IRQHandler(&hcan1);
}

/* USER CODE END 1 */
/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

Comment: I don't know this particular controller, but your timeseg tq settings look fishy. Where are they supposed to set the sync point for CAN1 and CAN2 respectively? You should always aim to get it as close to 87.5% as possible. See [What are the most common causes of CAN bus communication errors?](https://electrical.codidact.com/q/276251) for some advise about sync point and clock.

Comment: Yes thanks for the suggestion. Now I've changed Tseg values so as to match 87.5%.using http://www.bittiming.can-wiki.info/. But still the problem is there. Updated in the code posted. Please relook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem. Got help from ST community. Please refer to the link below.

> https://community.st.com/s/feed/0D53W00000RQCwgSAH?t=1608012202888

Problem was filter configuration for CAN1 and CAN2. There are 28 filter banks (0-27) split between CAN1 and CAN2. First half (0-13) for CAN1 and the rest for CAN2. So just make some changes in the code posted above -

> CAN 1:
>
> sFilterConfig.FilterBank = 0;
>
> :
>
> sFilterConfig.SlaveStartFilterBank = 14;
>
> CAN2:
>
> sFilterConfig.FilterBank = 14; // previously 0
>
> :
>
> sFilterConfig.SlaveStartFilterBank = 14; // previously 27

Thanks to [Lundin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584518/lundin) for suggesting sync point. Use this website for CAN Bit time calculations for various chips -

> http://www.bittiming.can-wiki.info/